# Why is this async for loop that slow?

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, for-loop

I have the following for-loop:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < packets2.Count; i++)
{                       
    dosimulationasync(packets2[i]);                        
}

stopwatch.Stop();                    
logit("Time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The `dosimulationasync` is something like this:

```
private async Task dosimulationasync(SimulationPoint mypoint)
{
    await TaskEx.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allobjects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (allobjects[i].ID == mypoint.ID)
            {
                allobjects[i].setvalue(mypoint);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that the first for loop, catching with the `stopwatch`, gets very slow the more values it has to handle (like 13 values take already around Time: 300 ms). I thought that by calling the `dosimulationasync` method asynchronously the first for-loop would continue at once.

I have no explanation why it gets that slow, even in case the `dosimulationasync` routine is slow, it should not influence the first for-loop, right?

What am I doing wrong? How can I "dispatch" the `dosimulationasync`?

Comment: You should consider using an IDE like Visual Studio Express or SharpDevelop; these IDE's will properly format your code for you.  Having the indentation and braces in the wrong place makes your code difficult to read and understand.

Comment: If you're using TaskEx.Run, that suggests you're still using the CTP... can you reproduce this with a short but *complete* program on the released version of .NET 4.5?

Comment: I would also try `Parallel.For(0, packets2.Count, i => { dosimulationasync(packets2[i]); });` to see the difference

Comment: @OndraMorský `await` doesn't mean it will stop, it means that it will wire up the remainder of the method as a continuation.  That said, since the OP never waits on the task returned from `dosimulationasync` he may as well just remove all references to async/await; it wouldn't change the code in any functional way.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You have to be careful with fine-grained parallelism; if you're just doing a quick lookup-and-set, you should probably be batching them or the overhead of `Task.Run` will impact your timing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case, the async/awaits will not help you.
The parallel method is dosimulationasync, but there is nothing in it to process in parallel.
I would completely remove async/await and use the Parallel.For in your main method:

```
Parallel.For(0, packets2.Count, (i) =>
{                       
    dosimulationasync(packets2[i]);                        
});
```

But make sure you can have parallel reads from packets2

Comment: `dosimulationasync` is just creating the tasks and scheduling them, it won't take a long time at all (since the code isn't actually waiting on those tasks).  The *scheduling* of tasks doesn't need to be done in parallel, and shouldn't take a long time.

Comment: I missunderstood the question. I thought he wants to measure the real work. My bad.

Comment: Thank you very much all helpers! The strange thing is, removing all the async Task - TaskEx.Run stuff and adding the Parallel.For() => .. stuff results in a much faster handling! Not that I do understand why async Task - TaskEx.Run is slower than a simple void () ..., but indeed I run now with 50 ms on 13 elements in the packets2-list (compared to 300 ms before).